# Send and Receive data from MySQL server through php in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am new to android. My issue is, I need a search bar and populate results in `list-view` from `Database` Containing 2 columns. One is for Name and other for Address. When I click item in list view it should display  $Address in Toast message.

***** MY PHP CODE *****

```html
<?php
$servername = "mysql4.000webhost.com";
$username = "a7239494_notice";
$password = "testpwd";
$dbname = "a7239494_noticeb";

$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
  echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$vname=$_POST['vname'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE Name='$vname'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($query)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $data[]=$row;
  }
    print(json_encode(array("results"=>$data)));
}else
{
  echo('Not Found ');
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

```html
***** MY ANDROID JAVA CODE *****
public void send(View v) {
    try {

       
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myurl)
        try {
           
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vname",name ));    //here name is click item on list view
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
     
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
           

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                
                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String s = e.getString("Name");
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an API in PHP and fetch your data through an HTTP URL connection class in android and after populate the response in your List.
You can use a list of libraries to connect to API in android like [https://square.github.io/retrofit/](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [http://square.github.io/okhttp/] (http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: You should use openURLConnection because your code is deprecated now. Or you should use some library like volley or asynHttpClient for doing same.

Comment: What is the error ? .No response and no error .?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1X_ohccpBK9aDhoNkdyMlk5Wm8/view  <== this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Get data in json format from your server and use Okhttp, Retrofit, Volley, etc.. any of them from android side to parse that data and display in your listView.

Most important thing is you have run your web service in AysncTask.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1X_ohccpBK9aDhoNkdyMlk5Wm8/view  <== This is my project.